Which window is considered the main window in Process.CloseMainWindow()
I would like to update my executable. To do this, I am first closing the executable's process (if open). Looking at my options, it looks like Process.CloseMainWindow is the recommended method.
How does the process decide what the main window is? I know how to set the application's main window, but I do not see an option to set the process' main window. The window I want to close is not the window opened on startup. It is also possible that the application will have multiple windows open. I haven't been able to find this information online.
I am using wpf if it is relevant.

Have you seen this related post?

Every window has a handle number.   The handle number are assigned numerically.  So the Main Window is the child window of the process with the lowest handle number.

Thanks. I was concerned that it had something to do with Focus. I wanted to make sure that the window does not change based on what my users click on.
